# SQL: Build table of numbers up to a variable input number inside CTE

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

I'm building a CTE in Snowflake that needs to return a table of values based on a variable derived from the max value in a table.  Is it possible to set a variable in a CTE?

Here is my query that I'm working with:

```
WITH MAX_VAL_QUERY (
SELECT MAX(COL1) FROM SOURCE_TABLE
),

MAX_VAL_VAR_QUERY AS (
SET MAX_VAL_VAR AS (SELECT MAX_VAL FROM MAX_VAL_QUERY LIMIT 1)
),

NUMS AS (
SELECT 1 AS VAL
UNION ALL
SELECT VAL + 1 AS VAL
FROM NUMS
WHERE NUMS.VAL <= MAX_VAL_VAR
)

SELECT * FROM NUMS;
```

Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [GENERATOR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/generator.html):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SEQ4()) AS NUM
FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT=>10000)) sub  -- ROWCOUNT is arbitrary here
WHERE NUM <= (SELECT MAX(COL1) FROM SOURCE_TABLE);
```

---

> Is it possible to set a variable in a CTE?

Not in a CTE but before:

```
SET maxval = (SELECT MAX(COL1) FROM SOURCE_TABLE);

WITH RECURSIVE NUMS AS (
  SELECT 1 AS VAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT VAL + 1 AS VAL
  FROM NUMS
  WHERE NUMS.VAL <= $maxval
)
SELECT * FROM NUMS;
```

Comment: This helps a lot with the tip on the generator but that specific code threw an error; however, I found that the following works; is this valid: SELECT SEQ4() AS NUM
FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT=>10000)) sub  -- ROWCOUNT is arbitrary here
WHERE NUM <= (SELECT MAX(COL1) FROM SOURCE_TABLE)
ORDER BY 1